# Найти процесс с помощью pgrep в формате сначала_слово+пробел+*?

Tags: bash, процесс, grep

Нужно найти процесс начинающийся со слова gpg далее пробел и далее любые другие слова/символы. Делаю так

```
$ pgrep -n "^gpg[[:blank:]]*"
1190
$ ps 1190
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   1190 ?        SLs    0:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
```

По идее должно ничего найти поскольку у процесса 1190 после gpg следует тире, а не пробел. Не знаю как исправить, вроде все правильно.

Answer (score 1):

`pgrep` по умолчанию ищет в имени исполнимого файла. Ваша строка поиска подразумевает, что вам нужен исполнимый файл, внутри которого пробел. Вы уверены, что хотите именно этого? Если вам нужно строго процесс `gpg`, то ищите `pgrep -n '^gpg$'`

Если же вам нужно искать внутри командной строки, то нужно добавить ключ `-f`. Однако в этом случае вы не найдёте `/usr/bin/gpg bla-bla`, так как строка начинается с `/usr/bin/`. Нужно искать `pgrep -n -f '(^|/)gpg '` - после `gpg` достаточно поставить пробел.

Ну и чтобы два раза не вставать, можно добавить ключ `-a`, который выведет номер процесса и командную строку

Answer (score 0):

`[[:blank:]]*` где `*` означает что пробелов может быть **0(ноль)** или больше, если хотите 1 или больше пробелов то тогда ставьте `+` вместо `*`